# Must a custom table view cell be prototype cell instead of static cell?

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have been googling and only seemed to be able to find examples of how to create custom cell as prototype cell.

My question is: Can I create custom table view cell as static cell?

Thanks in advance!
Eve

Answer (score 0):

No, in Storyboard you can edit your cell like you want by dragging objects into your cell.

You just have to make a new class of UITableViewCell and use that one in Storyboard, connect everything up if needed and use the following methods:

```
#import "YourTableViewCell.h"
- (YourTableViewCell *)tableView:(YourTableViewCell *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

....

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

}

- (void)configureCell:(YourTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
```